# How to access array element inside JS object?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with accessing element inside an array. Here is a sample code:

```
var Core = {

    customNames: {
        '1':    [ 'Power Off' ],
        '21':   [ 'TV', 'Bedroom' ]
    },

    render: function() {
        $.each( Core.devices.result, function( i, obj ) {
            var name = Core.customNames[obj.idx][1] ? Core.customNames[obj.idx][1] : obj.Name;
        });
    }

};
```

obj.idx is a variable, let say with value 21. How to access 'Bedroom' in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: devices doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Hey Travis, it's just a part of the code, devices are defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

try `this` in the render function!

```
render: function() {
        var that = this;
        $.each( this.devices.result, function( i, obj ) {
            var name = that.customNames[obj.idx][1] ? that.customNames[obj.idx][1] : obj.Name;
        });
    }
```

you have to set `that` because the scope inside the `$.each` changes!

Here is an example I tested and it worked:

```js
var thing = {
    customNames: {
        '1':    [ 'Power Off' ],
        '21':   [ 'TV', 'Bedroom' ]
    },
    log: function(){
        console.log("This got logged inside here: " + this.customNames['21'][0]);
    }
}

thing.log()
```

Greetings!

Comment: Unfortunately... "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined" :(

Comment: could it be possible that `that.customNames[obj.idx]` is undefined because the key `obj.idx` is not found in the dictionary?

Comment: Yep, exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It wasn't problem with accesing array element, but with incomplete customNames object. Proper code:

```
var name = Core.customNames[obj.idx] != undefined ? Core.customNames[obj.idx][0] : obj.Name;
```

Comment: okay, maybe you can tag my answer as the answer then, seemed like it works!